# Android: Not able to get current location in Google Map fragment

Tags: android, dictionary, fragment

```
public class location_a extends Fragment {

    TextView location;
    MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_a, container, false);

        location = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.add);

        location.setText("Plot -315\nNext to Taj Hotel\nNear layout\nBangalore - 5600092\nKarnataka");
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        return rootView;
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            SupportMapFragment mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment));
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "come in" + mMap, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //mMap = fm.getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "come in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {


        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(12.9120074,77.64910951)).title("Winfo Global"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(13.0120074,77.94910951)).title("xyz builder"));

        // Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Get the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Get Current Location
        //  Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (myLocation!=null) {
            double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
            double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
            String locLat = String.valueOf(latitude) + "," + String.valueOf(longitude);
            // set map type
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

            // Get latitude of the current location
            /// double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

            // Get longitude of the current location
            ///double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

            // Create a LatLng object for the current location
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            LatLng myCoordinates = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myCoordinates, 12);
            mMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);
            // Show the current location in Google Map
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(myCoordinates)      // Sets the center of the map to LatLng (refer to previous snippet)
                    .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
                    .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                    .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                    .build();                 // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        }
        // Zoom in the Google Map
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
        // mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("You are here!").snippet("Consider yourself located"));
    }

}
```

HERE mMap shows always NULL so it not enter into if statment

```
if (mMap != null) {Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "comein", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setUpMap();
            }
```

pls help me to solve problem

Comment: Improved code formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It always null if Google Play services APK is not available in application, please can you check with your code

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
GoogleMap mMap = mapFrag.getMap();
```

[Check here](https://github.com/dhaval0122/DJ-Android-/blob/master/getDirectionGoogleMap/src/com/DJAndroid/getDirection/showMaps.java) for full source code and sample

**Edit**

Make sure you have written following code in your layout to get map fragment from id.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: I fallow your code, after running , In emulater shows Unfortunately stopped..   PLEASE CAN YOU HELP ME

Comment: Can you please once check this in real device.. and also post your logs for application stop.

Comment: Yes i checked in my device also...same Unfortunately App is stopped and here my problem statement is, In Tabview such as Tab1,Tab2,Tab3 and Tab4..., in Tab3 i try to integrate Map Location, here Map ll displayed but current location not detecting. my code is above please check

Comment: I need your logcat output what causes unfortunate application stopping.

Comment: Process: only.fo.DDROID, PID: 23024
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMap()' on a null object reference
            at only.fo.DDROID.guests_user.projects_a.location_a.setUpMapIfNeeded(location_a.java:54)
            at only.fo.DDROID.guests_user.projects_a.location_a.onCreateView(location_a.java:42)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)

Comment: Check my edited answer. I guess you have not declared support map fragment in your layout file. Make sure it is there

Comment: I changed in XML file also again like Unfortunately stopped:       Process: only.fo.DDROID, PID: 2393
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMap()' on a null object reference
            at only.fo.DDROID.guests_user.projects_a.location_a.setUpMapIfNeeded(location_a.java:52)
            at only.fo.DDROID.guests_user.projects_a.location_a.onCreateView(location_a.java:42)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)

Answer (score 0):

mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17);